# selectOneMenu with selectItems

Tags: java, jsf

I am trying to make a filter using selectOneMenu.

I have two categories, when one is selectect, must filter the results shown, and also the second category.

JSF code:

```
<div id="box-categories" class="box-left">
            <b>Filter by topic</b>
            <h:selectOneMenu id="cat1" binding="#{interfaceContainer.documentFormContainer.selectOnes['cat1'].selectOne}" rendered="true"  onchange="javascript:refreshResults(); return false;">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{interfaceContainer.documentFormContainer.selectOnes['cat1'].items}" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
            <b>and subtopic</b>
 <h:selectOneMenu id="cat2" binding="#{interfaceContainer.documentFormContainer.selectOnes['cat2'].selectOne}" rendered="true"  onchange="javascript:refreshResults(); return false;" value="#{interfaceContainer.documentFormContainer.selectOnes['cat2'].value}">
                                        <f:selectItems value="#{interfaceContainer.documentFormContainer.selectOnes['cat2'].items}" />
                                </h:selectOneMenu>
        </div>
```

But I have problems when I try to get the values using this java code:

```
public String getStringValue(){
      if ( this.selectOne ==null || this.getSelectOne().getValue()==null)
          return "";
      return this.getSelectOne().getValue().toString();
  }
```

I realised that the problem is just with getValue(), because debugging, this.getSelectOne() is in the rigth value, but this.getSelectOne().getValue() is null.

Any idea??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

`UIInput#getValue()` will return null when you attempt to access it during any phase *before* the Update Model Values phase. You're apparently accessing it at the "wrong" moment in the JSF lifecycle. Anyway, creating dependent dropdown menus in JSF without help of a shot of Ajax is terrible.

Long story short, here's how to do it: [Populate child menu's](http://balusc.blogspot.com/2007/10/populate-child-menus.html) (with complete and working code examples).

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
My problem was that I must include everything in a form tag.
Thanks